# ImageResizer on Mono

Tags: mono, imageresizer

I get the following error when using the ImageResizer module on Mono in Linux:

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Argument is out of range. Parameter name: date

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: date
  at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.SetLastModified (DateTime date) [0x00046] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs:225 
  at ImageResizer.Caching.ResponseHeaders.DefaultApplyToResponseMethod (IResponseHeaders headers, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCacheHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x00dad] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1368 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:932 

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8 (tarball Sat Dec 31 02:07:23 UTC 2011); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

Here is the debug sheet:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      07/09/2012 14:15:41

3 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal is not supported on this runtime (are you running Mono?)
            It may be possible for users to bypass UrlAuthorization rules you have defined for your website, and access images that would otherwise be protected. If you do not use UrlAuthorization rules, this should not be a concern. You may also re-implement your security rules by handling the Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage event.

(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use


You are not using any paid bundles.

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Apache on Unix 2.6.39.2 and CLR 4.0.30319.1
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: 
Executing assembly: /usr/bin/mono
IntegratedPipeline: False

Loaded assemblies:

System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Messaging                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Mono.Data.Tds                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0        
Mono.Security                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0        
System.Security                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Mono.CSharp                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
App_global.asax_199cffe9                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
dotless.Core                             Assembly: 1.3.0.3         File: 1.3.0.3         Info: 1.3.0.3
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.2.3.302       File: 3.2.3.302       Info: 3-2-beta-3  Commit: 245e873
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.2.3.302       File: 3.2.3.302       Info: 3-2-beta-3  Commit: 245e873
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.20105.0    
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 3.5.594.0
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Mono.Posix                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0        
Mono.WebServer2                          Assembly: 0.4.0.0        
mod-mono-server4                         Assembly: 2.10.2.0       
Mono.Web                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         Info: 0.0.0.1
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.0.0         Info: 0.0.0.1
mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version...

Comment: AFAIK latest Mono version is `2.10.8`, and latest ImageResizer version is `3.2.3` - which is what I have.

Comment: Since V3.2.0, The DefaultApplyToResponseMethod converts the date to UTC and compares against DateTime.UtcNow before calling SetLastModified. I don't see how the value could possibly be out of range.... Can you switch to source and set a breakpoint? This is crazy...

Comment: Unfortunately, my development machine is Windows (Visual Studio) and everything is fine there. I get these errors on a headless linux machine with no MonoDevelop - so no breakpoints.

Comment: Relevant mono files: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs and https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web.Abstractions/System.Web/HttpCachePolicyWrapper.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically a bug in Mono - Both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 convert the date to universal time before performing the conversion, while mono compares it to the local server time, failing to even normalize the two variables to ensure they have matching time zones.

#### Mono [See code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs)

```
        public void SetLastModified (DateTime date)
        {

            if (date > DateTime.Now)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("date");

            if (have_last_modified && date < last_modified)
                return;

            have_last_modified = true;
            last_modified = date;
        }
```

#### .NET (both V2 and V4) (Use ILSpy, search HttpCachePolicy with System.Web loaded)

Or, click [this link](https://gist.github.com/3080465) to see the disassembly.

Psuedocode for SetLastModified(DateTime date):

1. Convert date to universal time.
2. Round datetime down to the nearest multiple of 10,000,000 ticks
3. Verify that value is less than DateTime.UtcNow, and throw an exception if it's not.
4. If the local copy of the value has been set before and is 'newer' than this value, leave it alone.
5. Otherwise set the local copy of the value to the universal time version of the parameter.

#### Calling code (ImageResizer), /Core/Caching/ResponseHeaders.cs

```
        //Sets the Last-Modifed: header
        //The check against the current time is because  files served from another server may have a modified date in the future, if the clocks are not synchronized.
        //ASP.NET incorrectly blocks an future modified date from being sent, with an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        DateTime utc = headers.LastModified.ToUniversalTime();

        if (utc != DateTime.MinValue && utc < DateTime.UtcNow) {
            context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(utc);
        }
```

Finding a workaround to this that won't break something isn't very simple. MS SQL provides LastModified values in un-specified time zones, while filesystems provide UTC but can be in the future if they're from a remote server.

Since incoming DateTime values often don't include a timezone flag, normalization is very important.

Converting to UTC, testing, converting back to local, testing, then assigning might be a valid workaround.

I suggest editing /Core/Caching/ResponseHeaders.cs, method DefaultApplyToResponseMethod to use the following statement

```
    if (utc != DateTime.MinValue && utc < DateTime.UtcNow && utc.ToLocalTime() < DateTime.Now) {
        context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(utc.ToLocalTime());
    }
```

Please let me see if you notice a flaw in the logic; if I it works for you and passes the beta test it might be integrated into a future release.

Comment: I'm going to vote down because of two reasons:
1) you're already proposing of using a workaround instead of actually fixing the bug (remember, Mono is open source), which may be even easier
2) by showing the ILSpy'ed code from MS.NET you're preventing everybody to contribute to Mono (this rule is in their policies)

Comment: #1 is an absurd reason for a downvote. #2 is interesting, as I've never seen that policy (although I'm not a contributor either). 

Since .NET development is completely impossible without ILSpy or something similar, I'm a bit skeptical. Why don't you provide an alternate phrasing of the answer that meets your criteria?

Comment: Nope, you're still proposing the use of ILSpy, virtually rendering people into the impossibility of contributing to Mono, therefore, impeding them to fix the actual bug.

Please remove the mention to ILSpy. The only things you need to know to fix a Mono bug is two: 1) the input to the method, 2) the output/expectation that MS.NET meets, and how Mono differs on this. You don't need to know the implementation of MS.NET.

Comment: Or even if you remove the mention to ILSpy and the link to the disassembly, you're still explaining in pseudocode what Microsoft's implementation is. Please remove that, it is copyrighted material.

Comment: Explaining the logic is not a derivative work under US copyright law. Go troll somewhere else.

Comment: Strongly disagree with knocte. This answer shows proof. There is no better answer than one that offers proof.